# Warum wird das Akkusativ-Objekt in einem passiven Satz zum Subjekt?

Tags: passive, objects

Es geht um den Unterschied in den folgenden drei Passiv-Konstruktionen:

Satz mit Dativ-Objekt:

> Ich helfe meinem Freund.
>   Meinem Freund wird (von mir) geholfen.

Satz mit Genitiv-Objekt:

> Wir gedenken der Toten.
>   Der Toten wird (von uns) gedacht.

Satz mit Akkusativ-Objekt:

> Ich sehe meinen Freund.
>   Mein Freund wird (von mir) gesehen.

In den ersten beiden Beispielen behalten die Objekte ihren Kasus bei und die Sätze haben schlicht kein Subjekt, während das Akkusativ-Objekt im dritten Beispiel in den Nominativ gesetzt und zum Subjekt wird.

Eine Freundin von mir lernt deutsch und war davon verwirrt, dass sie in einem Satz kein Subjekt finden konnte. Als ich ihr erklärt habe, dass nicht jeder Satz ein Subjekt haben muss und Beispiele gesucht habe, ist mir die oben genannte Besonderheit zum ersten mal aufgefallen. Ich habe ihr die Regeln erklärt, aber ich kann keine "zufriedenstellende" Begründung finden, warum diese Ausnahme existiert. Ich würde mich sowohl über eine inhaltliche, als auch eine syntaktische Erklärung freuen.

Comment: Ich sehe eigentlich in deinen ersten beiden Beispielen keine Sonderfälle der Regel "Passiv wird gebildet, indem das Akkusativ-Objekt das Subjekt wird und das Verb eine Passiv-Form annimmt." Hat der Satz kein Akkusativ-Objekt, dann hat der Passivsatz halt kein Subjekt. Vergisst man das Wort "Akkusativ" in der Regel, hat man in andren Sprachen, die keine Objekte im Dativ oder Genitiv (mehr) kennen, kein Problem. Im Deutschen halt schon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die generelle Regel, wie man im Deutschen das Passiv bildet, lautet eben:

> Das Akkusativ-Objekt des Satzes wird zum Subjekt, die Verbform wird durch eine Passiv-Form ersetzt.

(und alles Andere bleibt, wie's ist)

Hat der Satz kein Akkusativ-Objekt, hat der Passivsatz dazu eben kein Subjekt. Ein Genitiv- oder Dativ-Objekt bleibt Genitiv- oder Dativ-Objekt im Passivsatz.

Viele andere Sprachen, die keine Dativ- oder Genitiv-Objekte kennen, können in dieser Regel den "Akkusativ" weglassen und trotzdem eine Menge richtiger Passivsätze bilden. Im Deutschen gilt das eben nicht.

Das Deutsche ist hier ein bißchen besonders, weil die Menge sinnvoller Sätze, die man ohne Akkusativ-Objekt (auch mit intransitiven Verben) bilden kann, sehr viel größer ist, als in vielen anderen Sprachen. Deine "kritischen" Beispiele zeigen das sehr deutlich. Es ist eben die Eigenschaft des Akkusativs (siehe auch "Leideform"), dass er den passiven "Empfänger" der Aktion ausdrückt und damit im Passiv automatisch zum Subjekt wird.

Nimmt man das Englische als Beispiel her, sieht man, dass es dort an sich "wildere" Ausnahmen in diesen Fällen gibt:

Ein Satz im Aktiv könnte dort lauten:

> I gave him a present

und es gibt zwei mögliche Passivsätze dazu, in denen entweder das direkte oder indirekte Objekt zum Subjekt werden kann:

> A present was given
>
> He was given a present

Welcher von den beiden Passiv-Sätzen ist denn nun "der richtige"? Der letzte Passivsatz ist im Deutschen gar nicht bildbar, weil er der obigen Regel widersprechen würde.

Answer (score 5):

Die »Ausnahme« des Akkusativobjekts, das zum Subjekt wird, ist eigentlich der Normalzustand. In den meisten europäischen Sprachen, die ein Passiv kennen, können nur transitive* Verben ins Passiv gesetzt werden: solche, die eben ein Akkusativobjekt haben, das zum Subjekt werden kann. Das Deutsche ist hier toleranter, es können sogar nicht-transitive Verben ins Passiv gesetzt werden.

In allen mir bekannten indogermanischen Sprachen wird im Passiv das ehemalige (Akkusativ-) Objekt zum Subjekt; das Subjekt, wenn es erhalten wird, bekommt eine neue Rolle, die man grob mit »Präpositionalobjekt« umschreiben könnte. Das ist die Kernfunktion der Passivkonstruktion: Das, was eigentlich unbeteiligtes »Handlungsopfer« ist, wird zum Subjekt des Satzes, hervorgehoben, nach vorne gestellt. Dies ist auch im Deutschen der Fall: Wo ein Akkusativobjekt vorliegt, wird es, analog zu Französisch, English usw., zum Subjekt.

Dass hierbei die grammatikalischen Fälle getauscht werden, liegt an der neuen Rolle, die das ehemalige Objekt im Passivsatz zugewiesen bekommt. Plötzlich richtet sich das Verb in Person und Zahl nach dem ehemaligen Objekt, demnach ist der Akkusativ als Fall nicht mehr geboten, stattdessen der Nominativ.

Ich kreise hier ein bisschen immer wieder um die gleiche Aussage, denn letztendlich »ist es einfach so«. Andere, in der Regel nicht-indogermanische Sprachen können andere Regeln für ihr Passiv haben, wieder andere kennen überhaupt kein Passiv in dieser Form.

---

**Anmerkung:**

* Im Rahmen dieser Antwort gelte: *transitiv* = besitzt ein Akkusativobjekt.

Comment: Dann würde ich meine Frage evtl. umgekehrt formulieren und fragen, warum dann das Dativ-Objekt nicht zum Subjekt des Satzes wird. Ich sehe sozusagen einfach keine inhaltlichen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Situationen, dass meinem Freund geholfen wird oder dass er gesehen wird. Wenn die einzige Antwort "Es ist einfach so" ist, dann muss ich mich natürlich damit abfinden. Als Nebenbemerkung: Im Japanischen gibt es eine passive Form: 携帯を盗まれた。"Mein Handy wurde gestohlen."

Comment: @Yannik Okay, das mit Japanisch schaue ich nochmal im Detail nach, aber in deinem Satz behält das Handy im Japanischen das Objektpartikel を, es handelt sich also um kein grammatikalisches Passiv im eigentlichen Sinn.

Comment: So ist es. Am wichtigsten ist der erste Satz - Die Frage ist ein bißchen auf den Kopf gestellt und stellt das "normale" Passiv als "Ausnahme" dar. Dieser Fall sollte eigentlich für einen Fremdsprachler am leichtesten zu verstehen sein, da man annehmen kann, dass seine Sprache das genauso macht.

Comment: Im Englischen und den meisten romanischen Sprachen gibt es Fälle nur noch bei den Pronomen und den Unterschied zwischen Dativ und Akkusativ gibt es nicht mehr. Im Deutschen ist das eben noch der Fall.

Comment: @RHa Im Französischen »übernimmt« die Präposition *à* »die Funktion des Dativs«, wenn man so will. »Je lui donne un cadeau« => »Un cadeau lui est donné«. Nicht möglich: »Il est donné un cadeau«. Im Englischen ist das, wenn ich ein bisschen mehr darüber nachdenke, weniger klar. Vielleicht ist das allgemeine Passiv ein Feature der germanischen Sprachen …?

Comment: Folgenden Satz verstehe ich nicht: "In allen mir bekannten indogermanischen Sprachen wird im Passiv das ehemalige Subjekt zum (Akkusativ-) Objekt [...]". Im Passiv tritt das ehemalige Subjekt doch entweder gar nicht oder mit Präposition als "Agensphrase" auf?

Comment: @DavidVogt "und umgekehrt" ist richtig. Andersrum hast du recht. Bin ich auch drübergestolpert. Der Rest des Absatzes geht auch nur auf das "und umgekehrt" ein.

Comment: @DavidVogt Du hast Recht, da war ein Denkfehler drin.

Answer (score 2):

Nominativ und Akkusativ stehen in einem besonderen Verhältnis zueinander, das sich nicht nur im Passiv zeigt. In der Linguistik wurde darauf aufbauend die Theorie des *strukturellen Kasus* entwickelt. Die zugrundeliegende Beobachtung war, daß Nominativ und Akkusativ "kontextabhängig" sind.

> Er<sub>1</sub> durchquerte zügig den Park<sub>2</sub>. (Aktiv)
>   Zügig wurde der Park<sub>2</sub> (von ihm<sub>1</sub>) durchquert. (Passiv)
>   Wir sahen ihn<sub>1</sub> zügig den Park<sub>2</sub> durchqueren. (AcI)
>   die Durchquerung der Nordwestpassage<sub>2</sub> (Nominalisierung)
>   die Durchquerung Amundsens<sub>1</sub>

Die Subskripte bezeichnen semantische Argumentstellen: 1 ist die Person, die sich bewegt und etwas durchquert und 2 ist das, was durchquert wird.

1 wird realisiert als: Subjekt im Aktiv, Agensphrase im Passiv, Akkusativ beim AcI, Genitiv in der Nominalisierung.

2 wird realisiert als: Akkusativ im Aktiv, Subjekt im Passiv, Akkusativ beim AcI, Genitiv in der Nominalisierung.

Comment: *Die Durchquerung Amundsens* ist ein schönes Beispiel, wo man bei einer Substantivierung eigentlich automatisch "Passiv" annimmt (Also, dass "Amundsen durchquert" wurde.)

Comment: Das ist wie mit der Vase und den zwei Gesichtern, die sich anschauen.

Answer (score 2):

> "Ich sehe sozusagen einfach keine[n] inhaltlichen Unterschied zwischen den
>   beiden Situationen, dass meinem Freund geholfen wird oder dass er
>   gesehen wird".

Hmm, ja, ich verstehe, was du meinst, aber es gibt ein Aber.

Ganz, ganz früher, als du und ich noch nicht geboren waren, wurde Schulkindern in Deutschbüchern und Grammatiken erklärt, dass das Akk.obj. den- / die- / dasjenige benenne, der / die / das etwas 'erleide'. In *Peter ißt den Apfel* 'erleidet' der Apfel das Gegessen-Werden. In *Peter schlägt den Hund* 'erleidet' der Hund die Schläge. Folglich hieß das Passiv konsequenterweise *Leideform*.

Weiterhin wurde erläutert, dass in den Sätzen *Ich helfe meinem Freund.* und *Wir gedenken der Toten.* niemand etwas 'erleidet', so dass diese Objekte nicht zum 'Satzgegenstand' im Nom. werden können. Was sie ja auch tatsächlich nicht können.

Ob der *Freund* in dem Satz *Ich helfe meinem Freund.* durch die Hilfe des Ich tatsächlich nichts erleidet, steht auf einem anderen Blatt, dem außersprachlichen. ;-)

Ich kann nicht beurteilen, ob der Rückgriff auf vorvorgestern deiner Freundin helfen kann, aber vielleicht wäre es einen Versuch wert.